# How onPressed: func is different from onPressed: () => func() in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have a class:

```dart
class Foo {
  void bar() {}
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```dart
Widget build() {
  late Foo foo;

  return Column(
    children: [
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: foo.bar, // Error: 
        child: Text('Use'),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => foo = Foo(), // Assigning foo here
        child: Text('Initialize'),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

> The late local variable 'foo' is definitely unassigned at this point. (Documentation)

As you can see I'm using the `late` keyword to give a hint to the analyzer that I'll be instantiating later, but I still see an error, why?

---

**Note**: I'm NOT looking for solutions on **HOW** to make it work but rather **WHY** it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are creating the list right away as part of creating the `Column` object for the `children` argument. The list contains two `ElevatedButton` objects which are also created right away as part of creating the list. For creating the first `ElevatedButton` we provide two arguments, `onPressed` and `child` with values which are resolved and send to the `ElevatedButton` constructor.

The problem is then that to resolve `foo.bar` it needs get `bar` from `foo`. But `foo` is `late` and has definitely not been assigned any value at this point since no other code have been running which could provide a value for it.

Notice that when we provide arguments to methods/constructors the values we getting are resolved before we run code inside the method/constructor. Also, we are getting a copy of the reference, so `foo.bar` needs to be resolved to some value since we cannot use this as some kind of pointer to the `foo` variable inside `build()` and later check if it is set to a value inside the `ElevatedButton` object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew almost everything you mentioned but my question was `onPressed: () => foo.bar()` is allowed but this is not `onPressed: foo.bar`. Do you mean that in former part, we are lazily invoking the call and in the later we are instantly invoking it?

Comment: `onPressed: () => foo.bar()` gives `onPressed` a function, which when executed runs `foo.bar()`. `onPressed: foo.bar` means resolve what function `foo.bar` points to right now, and give that function as parameter to `onPressed`. In both cases, we need to know for sure what function we need to give `onPressed`. But in the first case, the provided function is going to be a unnamed function we create at the spot. That function contains then a call `foo.bar()`. But this is not needed to be resolved before we call this unnamed function.

Comment: Again, parameters needs to be resolved to a value before entering the function itself. See it as if you have a function taking a `String` parameter. This parameter can come from a lot of different operations, but when you are inside your function, the parameter is a `String` and you can request it as much you like and it will keep the value because the value have been resolved before going into your method.

Comment: I should add that `onPressed: () => foo.bar()` (different from your question) is potentially not safe since we don't know when the function given as `onPressed` is executed and so if `foo` have got any value at that point. But Dart does not complain about this risk because `foo` is marked `late` and it is your job as a developer to ensure this is safe. The reason you get an error for `onPressed: foo.bar` is, again, that we know for sure here that it is impossible for `foo` to have gotten any value in your example and Dart can therefore give you an warning even if the field is marked `late`.